# Trying to create first Facebook project, keep getting android library projects cannot be launched

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to make my first facebook project.  After I first creat the project, it runs find.  When I try to add the facebooksdk, I get the following error when I try to run the app
"Android Library projects cannot be launched"
This is what I did
1. Create a new workspace folder
2. go to file->import->general->existing projects into workspace (select all)
3. create my project called myfirstfacebook
4. run it, runs fine
5. try to add facebook sdk by
  properties->android check mark is library and click on add, then select facebooksdk

now my project no longer runs

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the sdk. The sdk is a library that goes into your project.

Click your project that imports facebook, THEN hit run. If you're getting that error, you're trying to run it.

Comment: Hi,I'm a litte confuse, I get the error on the project I created.  The project runs fin when i first create it.  After i try to add facebook sdk by

Comment: Hi,I'm a litte confuse, I get the error on the project I created. The project runs fin when i first create it. After i try to add facebook sdk by
Properties – android then I check mark library, click on add and then click on Facebooksdk.  Now when I run my program I get that error message

Comment: You don't want to click on the facebooksdk and hit run. You are not supposed to run the sdk. Just run your main project.

Comment: Thank you for your time in answering my questions.  I'm not clicking on the facebook sdk, but my project to run.  Allso after I add the sdk to my project, my project has that red dot next to it saying it has errors.